how can i install utplsql through sqlplus commands?
I am trying to install utplsql framework and getting this error and sqlplus gets auto disconnected each time can someone guide me?

I created tablespace and new schema ut3 as sysdba and have been trying to run that install.sql srcipt but going through same error in image again and again

That's not necessarily an error. "Disconnected from Oracle..." is the natural output of the exit command, which is the last SQL*Plus command at the end of the script install_headless. Is that the script you used for the installation? If so, you might want to put the command prompt Installation complete right before the exit command, to help you debug exactly where the installation is exiting.
